# Generating points on a circle

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import random
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def circle():
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in range(0,1000):
        angle = random.uniform(0,1)*(math.pi*2)
        x.append(math.cos(angle));
        y.append(math.sin(angle));
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.show()
circle()
```

I've written the above code to draw 1000 points randomly on a unit circle. However, when I run this code, it draws an oval for some reason. Why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a circle -- The problem is that the aspect ratio of your axes is not 1 so it looks like an oval when you plot it.  To get an aspect ratio of 1, you can use:

```
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')  # before `plt.show()`
```

This is highlighted in a [demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/equal_aspect_ratio.html).

Comment: I don't quite understand...why wouldn't it just draw a circle inside the 1.5 to 1.5 axes?

Comment: While the axes span the same range (3 units) on both axes, the physical space that the canvas takes up in the x and y axes differs.  You need to tell matplotlib to make it the same explicitly.

Comment: Seems to me that this also needs to be before `plt.scatter(x, y)`

Answer (score 0):

You can just set figure size:

```
def circle():
x = []
y = []
for i in range(0,1000):
    angle = random.uniform(0,1)*(math.pi*2)
    x.append(math.cos(angle));
    y.append(math.sin(angle));
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

circle()